How to convert json string into json object of list if you are working with list of dictionary in c# lambda function using newtonso
I am working on a lambda api, and i need to get response in object of list.
here is my model:
public class Response
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> FailedTenant { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string,string>> FailedWaterMeter { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> SuccessfulTenant { get; set; }

    public List<Dictionary<string,string>> SuccessfulWaterMeter { get; set; }
    public Response()
    {
        FailedTenant = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        FailedWaterMeter = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        SuccessfulTenant = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        SuccessfulWaterMeter = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }
}

public class FailedTenant
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class FailedWaterMeter
{
    public string MeterNumber { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
public class SuccessfulTenant
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class SuccessfulWaterMeter
{
    public string MeterNumber { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}}

i have implemented this in my code like this:
        Response responseResult = new Response();

       
        foreach (FailedTenant failedTenant in failedTenants)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> failedTenantDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
              {"Email", failedTenant.Email},
              {"Message", failedTenant.Message}
            };

            responseResult.FailedTenant.Add(failedTenantDictionary);
            


        }

        foreach (FailedWaterMeter failedWaterMeter in failedWaterMeters)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> failedWaterMeterDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
               {"MeterNumber", failedWaterMeter.MeterNumber},
               {"Message", failedWaterMeter.Message}
            };
            responseResult.FailedWaterMeter.Add(failedWaterMeterDictionary);
        }

        foreach (SuccessfulTenant successfulTenant in successfulTenants)
        {
            byte[] messageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(successfulTenant.Message);
            successfulTenant.Message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes);

            Dictionary<string, string> successfulTenantDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                
                {"Email", successfulTenant.Email},
                {"Message", successfulTenant.Message}
            };
            responseResult.SuccessfulTenant.Add(successfulTenantDictionary);
        }

        foreach (SuccessfulWaterMeter successfulMeter in successfulWaterMeters)
        {
            byte[] messageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(successfulMeter.Message);
            successfulMeter.Message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBytes);
            Dictionary<string, string> successWaterMeterDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"Email", successfulMeter.MeterNumber},
                {"Message", successfulMeter.Message}
            };
            responseResult.SuccessfulWaterMeter.Add(successWaterMeterDictionary);
        }

        string message = string.Empty;
        if (responseResult.SuccessfulTenant.Count>0 && responseResult.SuccessfulWaterMeter.Count>0 && responseResult.FailedTenant.Count==0 && responseResult.FailedWaterMeter.Count == 0)
        {
            return BaseResponse.SuccessResponse("All Tenants Added Successfully");
        }

        else if(responseResult.SuccessfulTenant.Count>0 || responseResult.FailedTenant.Count>0 || responseResult.FailedWaterMeter.Count > 0 || responseResult.SuccessfulWaterMeter.Count>0) 
        {
            string jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseResult);
           
            return BaseResponse.FailureResponse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Some Tenants and Some Water Meters not added "+ " "+ jsonResponse));
        }
        else
        {
            string jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseResult.FailedTenant,Formatting.Indented);
           
            return BaseResponse.FailureResponse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("No Tenants Were Processed  " + "Failed Tenants: " + jsonResponse));
        }

and i am getting the response like this :
{\"Email\":\"tanmay@yopmail.com\",\"Message\":\"Email already exist,Please Use Another email!\"},{\"Email\":\"abhi@yopmail.com\",\"Message\":\"Email already exist,Please Use Another email!\"},{\"Email\":\"abhi@yopmail.com\",\"Message\":\"Email already exist,Please Use Another email!\"},{\"Email\":\"pihu@yopmail.com\",\"Message\":\"Email already exist,Please Use Another email!\"},{\"Email\":\"mihu@yopmail.com\",\"Message\":\"Email already exist,Please Use Another email!\"},{\"Email\":\"mihu@yopmail.com\",\"Message\":\"Email already exist,Please Use Another email!\"},{\"Email\":\"jinal@yopmail.com\",\"Message\":\"Email already exist,Please Use Another email!\"},{\"Email\":\"khyati@yopmail.com\",\"Message\":\"Email already exist,Please Use Another email!\"},{\"Email\":\"janadhi@yopmail.com\",\"Message\":\"Email already exist,Please Use Another email!\"}

but i want this in json object form like:
{"Email":"tanmay@yopmail.com","Message":"Email already exist"}

How will i do that , please help

What is your question? It is unclear about your requirement? Are you talking about the forwardslash ("") characters in your response string?

On what line are you getting a "response like this"?  Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] that we could compile, test, run and debug ourselves, as indicated in [ask]?

so it returns you array of objects instead one, so what is a problem?
